# Laravel show with relationships

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

How do you use the show function relationships? i know this works:

```
public show ($id) {   
    Model::with('relationship')->find($id);
}
```

but with the new format

```
public show(Model $model) {

}
```

how do you include the relationship?

i've tried

```
$model->with('relationship')->get();
```

but it changes the value from an object to an array, what would be the proper way to do this?

Comment: Why do you want eager loaded for one model?

Comment: To answer, you can't do this Model $model is same thing as Model::find($id);

Answer (score 2):

Lets [lazy eager load](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#lazy-eager-loading) that:

```php
public show(Model $model) {
    $model->load('relationship');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That's not a "new format". That's in fact Route model binding which is a convenient way to work as an API. https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#route-model-binding

When you have a route such as

```
Route::get('/users/{user}', [UserController::class, 'show']);
```

Your controller will receive the model already fetched from database.
If you need to use additional relationships you have 2 options (let's assume that user has a profile relationship):

Eager load on controller

```php
public show(User $user) {
    $user->load('profile');
    return $user;
}
```

Or eager load in your `RouteServiceProvider.php` by using explicit binding. https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#explicit-binding

```php
/**
 * Define your route model bindings, pattern filters, etc.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    Route::bind('user', function ($value) {
        return User::with('profile')->findOrFail($value);
    });
}
```

Therefore you will have the user with it's profile in your controller

Comment: Also, there is a third way of doing this, you can add $with variable to your Model class and include all the relationships you want to be loaded on each Model query.

Comment: @Victor could you please elaborate? I did not find anything related in docs.

Comment: UPDATE: Eager Loading By Default https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading-by-default

Comment: Interesting, I'd never seen that. I guess that's the most accurate way if this question regards  about loading relationships everywhere